# Enable/Disable Data Enable mechanisam in Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.2-jelly-bean, genymotion, nexus-s

I am using Genymotion Emulator with Nexus s and 4.2.2.

Previously i used regular AVD that we can create using Eclipse provided by ANDROID SDK.

In regular AVD we can enable/disable data packet access to internet by using

**Settings->Wireless&Networks->Data Enabled**

Or by pressing F8 key but i am unable to found it in Genymotion emulator.

Where i can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that on Genymotion.

If you want to test what your application will do without internet access, you can unplug your ethernet cable or switch off your Wi-Fi.
It's not the same but could still help to test your app.

Comment: In actual case i want to enable the Internet i am unable to Enable it.

Comment: Genymotion always have internet, using a simulated wifi network. If it is not working, It is probably a bug or a misconfiguration. Contact Genymotion support to get help.

Comment: Finally found the internet option in Genymotion is controlled through WI-FI.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to go into the Settings app, and turn off the Wi-Fi setting.

Answer (score 0):

I hade this problem.

If you disable the internet and try to debug your app, the app will not be able to connect to vs code debug server.

This what you should do.

1- in your emulator, click Debug/settings and change the `ip:port` to the following `localhost:your port eg 5555`

2- disable the wifi and your app will start without internet but still able to connect to vs code