# Android Emulator Network Interface

Tags: android, android-emulator, httpurlconnection

In my mac i have 2 networks, ethernet and wifi. Is there a way to force the emulator to go through only via WIFI?

**EDIT 1**
Using built-in emulator of the SDK. (Android Virtual Device)

Comment: Which emulator are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default emulator... if you have a other option pls say so!

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537559/enable-disable-data-enable-mechanisam-in-genymotion-emulator

Comment: I prefer GenyMotion (or Xamarin Android Player) for my Android emulator needs - must faster :)

Comment: @TeamTam no its not... i want the traffic that the emulator generates be directed to the Wifi interface, while the rest of the mac uses the regular ethernet...

Comment: sorry to join the party so late but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293249) can help other people with the same issue